# pods "kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-56tlr" not found

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, portforwarding

Currently I'm using microk8s to run local cluster.

When I run `k get pods -A`, this result shown

```
...
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-56tlr        1/1     Running   1          3d14h
...
```

Ok.. It means there's a pod kubernetes-dashboard running in kube-system namespace.

And I tried to port forward that pod 443 into 10443 and this result shows up

```
$ k port-forward kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-56tlr 10443:443
Error from server (NotFound): pods "kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-56tlr" not found
```

I mean, there it is. The pod is there. But it keeps denying it.

I don't understand this result and stuck with no progress. 
How can I port-forward my pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `k get pods -A` indicates that the pod is in the namespace `kube-system`. Unless a resource is in the default namespace, you must specify the namespace:

```
k port-forward -n kube-system kubernetes-dashboard-7ffd448895-56tlr 10443:443
```

Alternatively, you can update your context to use a different namespace by default:

```
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace=kube-system
```

After you do that you can work with resources in `kube-system` without setting `-n kube-system`.